# How to use NSURLSessionConfiguration - backgroundSessionConfiguration for POST

Tags: ios, post, nsurlsession

Am trying to use `NSURLSession` for uploading Images to the server using `POST`. Each time i may have more than 10 Images with big size. What i want to do is, do the `POST` in `backgroundSessionConfiguration` so even if user close the app background uploading should not be stopped and after finish show a notification. When i use `backgroundSessionConfiguration` for `NSURLSessionDownloadTask` for downloading from server every thing work perfect. But when i try to use it for `POST` with `NSURLSessionDataTask` am getting below error

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Data tasks are not supported in background sessions.'
*** First throw call stack:
```

After i googling for this error i found that the we should not use `backgroundSessionConfiguration` with `NSURLSessionDataTask`. I would like to know how to achieve background uploading for `POST`.

Comment: NSURLSessionDataTask is not Supported with Background session configuration.only download and upload task are allowed in background you can use NSURLSessionUploadTask.

Comment: Can we add post data with NSURLSessionUploadTask. Like Title, Description, etc along with images.

Comment: i never try with that but you can add [urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"]; in your url request.

Comment: I tried to add POST, but am getting this error 'Upload tasks in background sessions must be from a file'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this.

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"urlString"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:fileURL];
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask = [session uploadTaskWithRequest:request fromData:data
completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {}];
[uploadTask resume];
```

Comment: completion handler are not allowed in background session

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use backgroundSessionConfiguration you can't use the completion block calls. The Apple docs are very confusing on this and other points. I have successfully implemented background uploads after many hours of frustration. Since there isn't much info on the internets, I've decided to document my work.
https://medium.com/@KyleRStewart/zombie-uploads-with-ios-dd3b1f6b66
Hopefully this saves you some time.

Answer (score 0):

@johny.  Solution you proposed does not work if we want to support upload task in background. Correct way to support upload from background is using following method provided by Apple

*

```
/* Creates an upload task with the given request.  The body of the request will be created from the file referenced by fileURL */
*- (NSURLSessionUploadTask *)uploadTaskWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request fromFile:(NSURL *)fileURL;*
```

*